# Codeigniter header and footer include

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing

I'm trying to move from AngularJS to PHP Model-View-Controler framework and something doesn't stick to me, because I do to much repeating. In angular you can do simple include of footer and header and all magic happens in view depending od the route. But in Codeiginiter for every view you need to include header and footer. Is there any good practice in which you don't have to do the much repeating

**In angularjs i have simple.**

```
    <div ng-include='"templates/header.html"'></div>
    <div ng-view></div>
    <div ng-include='"templates/footer.html"'></div>
```

**And this is routing**

```
 .when("/", {
        templateUrl: "partials/home.html",
        controller: "PageCtrl"   
    })
    // Pages
    .when("/home", {
        templateUrl: "partials/home.html",
        controller: "PageCtrl",
    })
    .when("/about", {
        templateUrl: "partials/about.html",
         controller: "PageCtrl"
    })
```

**And this is how is done in CodeIgniter**

```
     public function home(){ 
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('about');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
   public function about(){ 
    $this->load->view('templates/header');
    $this->load->view('index');
    $this->load->view('templates/footer');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can put at the top and on the bottom of files:

View file:

```
<?php
$this->load->view('templates/header');
// your main file (index;about etc)
$this->load->view('templates/footer')
```

so, in controller you could load just main file i.e.

Controller file:

```
public function home()
{
    // $this->load->vars($data)
    $this->load->view('index');
}
```

Also study [Loader class](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/libraries/loader.html#CI_Loader::vars) to know how to set variables for all of those files.

Comment: Yeah it is not the same thing. In loads whole document all together i just wanted view to be loaded

Comment: If this is solving your question, you can accept the answer as well. :)

Answer (score 0):

> in your controller, you can user simple method as given bellow to
>   specify your header and footer to all yor page.

**Controller**

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {
    public function index()
    {   
        $headerData = array(
            "pageTitle" => "Home",
            "stylesheet" => array("home.css")
        );

        $footerData = array(
            "jsFiles" => array("home.js")
        );

        $viewData = array(
            "viewName" => "home",
            "viewData" => array(),
            "headerData" => $headerData,
            "footerData" => $footerData 
        );
    $this->load->view('template',$viewData); // load `Home` view to template file in view folder.
}
```

**View** (template.php)

```
$this->load->view("includes/header.php",$headerData);

$this->load->view($viewName.".php",$viewData);

$this->load->view("includes/footer.php",$footerData);
```